# the voiceover does not automatically read the "aria-labelledby" contained in my modal when it is displayed on the screen

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

I am trying to make a modal with `accessibility`. Basically, the modal gets a `child` and this `child` will be the content of the modal:

```
  <div
    id="modal"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="modal-label"
    aria-describedby="modal-desc"
    tabIndex={0}
    className="modal"
  >

    {*/  {children} */}

   <div className="flexContainer">
    <div id="modal-desc">
      <div>hey</div>
      <div>
        <div>This is the description</div>
        <div>I am a button</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="modal-label">This is the title</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

When the modal opens, the `voiceover` reads the texts as it is in the gif, but I don't know why it doesn't read the `aria-labelledby`. My idea is that I can pass any `child` to my modal and the voiceover reads everything that is contained in `aria-labelledby` and in `aria-describedby`.

[image]

how can I make the `voiceover` read "aria-labelledby" automatically?

[this is my live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-snow-rfuxpk)

```
const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

const Modal = ({ children }) => {
useEffect(() => {
  document.querySelector("#modal")?.focus();
}, []);

return (
  <div
    id="modal"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="modal-label"
    aria-describedby="modal-desc"
    tabIndex={0}
    className="modal"
  >
    {children}
  </div>
);
};

const ModalContent = () => {
return (
  <div className="flexContainer">
    <div id="modal-desc">
      <div>hey</div>
      <div>
        <div>This is the description</div>
        <div>I am a button</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="modal-label">This is the title</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
};

return (
<>
  <button
    aria-hidden="true"
    onClick={() => {
      setOpenModal(true);
    }}
  >
    open modal
  </button>
  {openModal && (
    <Modal>
      <ModalContent />
    </Modal>
  )}
</>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you're using aria-labelledby, however it may be that the content of your modal (`#modal-desc`) is being added *after* the modal container (`#modal`), so the `#modal-label` ID is not immediately available in the DOM when the modal first appears. Sometimes this can cause problems for screen readers when content (particularly content that is linked to aria-labelledby or aria-describedby) is added dynamically to the DOM.

A better way to ensure that your modal label is announced is to include it in the `aria-label` attribute in your dialog container, e.g.:

```
<div id="modal" role="dialog" aria-label="This is the title" aria-describedby="modal-desc" tabIndex="0" class="modal">
```

As an aside, you have `aria-hidden="true"` on your "open modal" button. You should remove this because it hides the button from screen readers.

Comment: thanks, can you help me with this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71648712/aria-describedby-is-not-fully-read-unless-there-is-an-aria-labelledby