# "aria-describedby" is not fully read unless there is an "aria-labelledby"

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I'm trying to get the `voiceover` to read only the `aria-describedby`, but it reads it this way ("I am a button" is not read):

[image]

Whereas if there is an element with id `aria-describedby="modal-label"` defined. the element with id `aria-labelledby="modal-desc"` is read completely ("I am a button" is read).

[image]
[image]

```
<div
 id="modal"
 role="dialog"
 aria-labelledby="modal-label"
 aria-describedby="modal-desc"
 tabIndex={0}
 className="modal"
>

{*/  {children} */}

  <div>
    {/* If no exists this div, modal-desc is not read completely */}
    <div id="modal-label">this is the title</div>

    <div id="modal-desc">
      <div>this is a descripcion</div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <button>I am a button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

How can I make the `aria-describedby` be read completely when there is no element with the `id` `modal-label` when the modal is opened?

[this is my live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-snow-rfuxpk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Could you post a CodePen example of your code so I can test it live in a browser? I can't see any reason why `aria-describedby` shouldn't work if the element referred to by `aria-labelledby` isn't present, but as I stated in my answer to your last question, it may be that the modal content isn't in the DOM (including the `#modal-desc`) when the screen reader processes the modal announcement. Would be much easier if I could see your example working in the browser to give more info.

Comment: @George this is my live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-snow-rfuxpk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @George you can look my code working here: https://rfuxpk.csb.app/

Comment: @George this is my code,you can see in an browser https://jqdnpl.csb.app/

Comment: The text "I am a button" is attached to the button element, whereas your `aria-describedby` and `aria-labelledby` are attached to the modal. You seem to be expecting to hear the button's accessible name when you have focus on the modal, but voiceover is instead probably only reading the accessible name for the modal. I suspect that this is the source of your problem.

Comment: how can i solve it? if i delete "#aria-labelledby" everything is read out even the button text @Josh

Comment: I would recommend removing the aria attributes from the modal. You may also want to look at how Bootstrap uses roles in their modal implementation. Notice that they have an inner div with a "document" role. I would recommend replicating that structure. You'll probably find that everything works after doing that. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/

Comment: It does seem to be a bug, but I would be surprised if putting an operable element (the button) inside something pointed to from `aria-describedby` would work without hitches. Do you need to include the button in the description? 
As @Josh suggests putting a document role inside a modal is a common workaround for VO dialog issues. 
Also, have you tried using an HTML5 `<dialog>` - I understand this is now (March 2022) working across all major browsers (not IE, ofc). https://caniuse.com/dialog
More on `<dialog>` at https://www.stefanjudis.com/blog/a-look-at-the-dialog-elements-super-powers/

Answer (score 4):

Your generated HTML should resemble something like this:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-label" aria-describedby="modal-desc" tabindex="-1">

    <!-- {children} -->

    <div role="document">
        <div id="modal-label">this is the title</div>

        <div>
            <div id="modal-desc">this is a description</div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button>I am a button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's worth noting that when both `aria-describedby` and `aria-labelledby` are both present, `aria-labelledby` seems to take precedence in the [accessible name computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.2/).

Additionally, your original example had the `ariadescribedby` element containing a button, which may cause problems.

> Note: The aria-describedby content should only be a text string.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-describedby

Depending on your screen reader and/or browser, you may get different behavior, but `aria-labelledby` would typically be read first, and then `aria-decribedby` may or may not be read afterwards, depending on the implementation.

`aria-decribedby` also may or may not be read on focus, depending on the implementation.

You should also pay special attention to the [limitations voiceover has](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/aria/aria-describedby_attribute) in supporting `aria-describedby`, as this might be preventing you from getting the exact behavior that you're looking for.

At the end of the day, `aria-describedby` may not end up being the right tool, if it's important information that everyone needs to understand to make sense of the content.